# How can we find the frequency of this curve?

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, frequency-analysis

I am stuck with this problem. I am struggling to find the frequency of this curve. It appears that peak are repeated in nature. I tried auto correlation function but it results in another saw tooth wave.

I have tried to use autocorrelation and fftfreq from numpy to extract the frequency. I tried peak detection as well. But these are not working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rU1Q.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjLRc.jpg

Comment: Hi Rahul, for completeness you should show the code of what you tried so far as well as the according ( negative ) results. It would also be nice if you could provide the data, as the images are not really helpful.

Comment: It looks a little bit like up and down every data point, if that's the case, the frequency is somewhat clear.

Comment: Look for a peak in the Fourier transformation (FFT). There are Numpy and SciPy functions for FFT.

Comment: @mikuszefski if you are correct, then a re-analysis or re-plot using *every other data point* will be smooth. I also suspect this might be the case here.